# Doctrine2 dont want to insert the columns in the table

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Here is my Insert Query, how can I tell that, `created_at`(current time-stamp), `is_active`(default 1) set in the mysql db structure needs to be taken.

When I omit the `$question->setCreatedAt($this->createdAt);` in the insert operation it shows me an ***Integrity constraint violation***, do you know what is the issue?

In the Questions table:

```
question:

id
question
created_by
created_at
modified_by
modified_at
is_Active
```

**Entity:**

```
    <?php

    namespace Library\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Base class for all the Entities
     * This class maps id, active, created and modified columns 
     *
     * @author 

 */
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $active;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_by", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $createdBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified_at", type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $modifiedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified_by", type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $modifiedBy;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getActive() {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function getCreatedBy() {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    public function getModifiedAt() {
        return $this->modifiedAt;
    }

    public function getModifiedBy() {
        return $this->modifiedBy;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setActive($active) {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy($createdBy) {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;
    }

    public function setModifiedAt($modifiedAt) {
        $this->modifiedAt = $modifiedAt;
    }

    public function setModifiedBy($modifiedBy) {
        $this->modifiedBy = $modifiedBy;
    }
}
```

**This is my `Question` Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Survey\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Survey\Entity\Survey;

/**
 * Description of Survey Questions
 *
 * @author Mubarak
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="survey_questions")
 */

class Question extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Survey\Entity\Survey", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="survey_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $surveys;

    public function getQuestion() {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion($question) {
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getSurveys() {
        return $this->surveys;
    }

//    public function setSurveys(ArrayCollection $survey) {
    public function setSurveys(Survey $surveys = null) {
        $this->surveys = $surveys;
    }

//    public function __toString() {
//        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
//    }
}
```

Here is my insert Operation:

```
public function insertQuestion($userId, $survey, $questionArr) {
        try{
            $question = new Question();
            $question->setQuestion($questionArr['question']);
            $question->setSurveys($survey);
            $question->setActive(1);
            $question->setCreatedBy($userId);
            $question->setCreatedAt($this->createdAt);
            $question->setModifiedBy($userId);
            $question->setModifiedAt($this->modifiedAt);
            $this->entityManager->persist($question);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            return $question;
        }catch(Exception $ex){
           throw new Exception("Couldnt insert the question");
        }
    }
```

This is Ok, its working properly, but i dont want to insert the Created_at, modified_at

```
public function insertQuestion($userId, $survey, $questionArr) {
            try{
                $question = new Question();
                $question->setQuestion($questionArr['question']);
                $question->setSurveys($survey);
                $question->setActive(1);
                $question->setCreatedBy($userId);
                $question->setModifiedBy($userId);
                $this->entityManager->persist($question);
                $this->entityManager->flush();
                return $question;
            }catch(Exception $ex){
               throw new Exception("Couldnt insert the question");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set default values it is best to set them in your object model where possible.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 * @var boolean
 */
protected $active = true;
```

For time-stamps though it is a bit of a different story...
I would suggest to take a look at **[the Gedmo doctrine extensions library](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions)** which includes solutions for `createdAt` and other common columns for your model. No need to reinvent the wheel... .

Comment: thanks, Regarding the active case, you are right, but created_at not working

Comment: @user3929758 Okay. I removed the `created_at` part from my answer. You should seriously check out the doctrine extensions...

Comment: is it Gedmo doctrine extensions library is a package of Doctrine2

Comment: @user3929758 You are supposed to use with Doctrine, but it is not an official Doctrine 2 repository...